# Regex java to mask

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I need a regex to mask this

```
\"documentoIdentificacionEmisor\" : \"X0000000D\"
```

and

```
"documentoIdentificacionEmisor" : "000004145D"
```

For second match with  this regex and mask

```
("documentoIdentificacion[\w]*"\s?\:\s?")([\w]{4})([\w]{1,8})  $1******$3
```

and mask

```
"documentoIdentificacionEmisor" : "******4145D"
```

but the first no
i need one regex for two expresions and mask

Comment: Looks like you just missing two optional literal backslashes? See [this](https://regex101.com/r/tily10/3). I haven't looked at the logic behind your current pattern. Maybe someone can come up with a smoother version.

Comment: What is the question? How to match the backslash before the double quote? Note that group 3 matches a digit too much I think `04145D` https://regex101.com/r/gUtbj6/1

Comment: Do you mean like this? `((\\?)"documentoIdentificacion\w*\2"\s?\:\s?")(\w{4})(\w{1,8})`  https://regex101.com/r/cexVp3/1 and replace with `$1******$4`

Comment: thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv

Answer (score 0):

```
("documentoIdentificacion[\w]*\\?"\s?\:\s?\\?")([\w]{4})([\w]{1,8})
```

Thanks to [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)